# Missed chaos flame for level 4 to 5 upgrade any recourse?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

I beat the last story boss, but in lost items no chaos flame shows up (some traveler items did though) and my blades of chaos are stuck on level 4. Am I permanently gimped or can I grind up enough of the funny resource to buy enough chaos flames to reach max level for the blades?

I backtracked to the Tyr's underground move the giant chains part, but can't go back into the Jotunheim tower either. Didn't find a convenient chaos flame lying on the ground.

Answer (score 4):

The final upgrade for your weapons doesn't come from a normal boss drop like all the previous materials. Instead you will need to trade a resource from "post game" activities to unlock it. Doing these will each unlock a Playstation trophy as well.

**For level 6 of the Leviathan Axe** you will need a *Chilling Mist of Nifheim* which you can find by

> Unlocking the workshop and opening the third golden chest from the left inside there.

This can be traded at a shop for a Frozen Flame and upgrade the axe to it's final level.

**For level 5 of the Blades of Chaos** you will need to get a *Raging Inferno of Mespelheim* which you get by

> Beating all six trials of Mespelheim and defeating the Valkyrie.

And again you go to a shop and trade it for the final Chaos Flame.

Comment: I'm not at the final level, I'm at the one prior going level 4 to 5.

Comment: @user1821961 If your blades are level 4 then nothing is wrong, the final level for the blades is 5. Only the Axe is level 6 max.